# simplexml_load_file fails with '&' in xml feed

Tags: php, xml, rss

Error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): feed.rss:2393: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mklbet\index.php on line 16

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): <title>We have a winner & it is ME</title> in C:\xampp\htdocs\mklbet\index.php on line 16
```

My problem is that when i use simplexml_load_file($url) - and the in the xml feed there is a '&' it will make an error - how can i get this to work?

```
if (file_exists($url)) {
       $tips = simplexml_load_file($url);

    } else {
        exit('Failed to open stream');
    }

        foreach ($tips->channel->item as $entry) {

            $title=htmlentities($entry->title);
}
}
```

This is how i wrote the code, i am getting the rss feed from another site so i cant edit the character

Comment: The XML-File you use is not correctly encoded - it has to be `&amp;` instead of `&`.

Comment: I am aware of that the feed looks like this:

<title>We have a winner & it is ME</title>
<link>http://www.links.com/tip/946079&amp;utm_medium=tips&amp;utm_campaign=feed-rss</link>

So it is only the title that is wrong, but other places it uses &amp; as it should - and i do not have access to edit the feed

Comment: As a hack you could replace "& " by "&amp; " before parsing, however, this won't work with "A&B" - Best way would be to inform the creator of the buggy RSS feed.

Comment: Did you see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674035/how-to-shut-up-simplexml-on-malformed-data