# simplexml_load_string - Exception => Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Tags: php, xml, laravel, simplexml, guzzle

I'm trying to parse a `GuzzleHTTP\PSR7\Response` into a `SimpleXMLElement` Object using `simplexml_load_string()` function. What I'm facing here is I get **Randomly** Exception that says :

> Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

and by randomly I mean once I pass successfully, once fail.

What is your suggestion for `simplexml_load_string()` input/ How to fix the Exception?

**PHP :**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string((string)$response->getBody());
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `simplexml_load_string` requires a string as it's first parameter that contains *well-formed XML*. If you do not provide such a string, don't expect the function to work.

In that case, handle the error case and you're fine: The function will return `false` if the string couldn't be parsed as XML. The PHP-manual has a whole page about that topic alone:

- [Dealing with XML errors (SimpleXML > Examples)](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-errors)

We should also have Q&A material here on site, for example:

- [simplexml error handling php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1307275/367456) (Aug 2009)
- [How to shut up simpleXML on malformed data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1674035/367456) (Nov 2009)